# Samba sharing from ubuntu to win7

Tags: permissions, samba

I have installed and configured a SAMBA server. So far it works well until I try to log in. When the password box pops up from a win7 machine, I enter the details but it says "wrong details". The second user I have set up doesn't have password restrictions, so I can log in directly into that account. The 3rd user I have set up, again tells me to get permission from the network administrator.

Any help on this getting resolved would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the samba logs for more details about the error. Make sure that you have  created the samba user and password correctly and added it the valid_user list. Try to reset the smb passwd for the user which is giving error.

In the samba configuration file /etc/samba/smb.conf, look for the folder share parameters. Ex. abc xyz and pqr users have the write permission to the share called sales:

```
[salesdoc]
path = /home/shared/sales
write list = abc xyz pqr
```

Likewise you can use following options:

```
read list: This option accepts a list of usernames or a group as its value. Users will be given read-only access to the share.
valid users: You can make a share available to specific users. Usernames or group names can be passed on as its value.
invalid users: Users or groups listed will be denied access to this share.
```

Comment: How do i view the valid_users list. I got to started on samba a month ago, and dont know all the commands yet

Comment: what i have done so far is:user1 -> [superuser]
comment = superuser
path = /home/samba/superuser
read only = no
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
valid users = superuser
public = no
writable = yes

This user only gives the following error when trying to login from windows net location: contact network administrator for permission.

Comment: [admin]
comment = admin
path = /home/samba/admin
read only = no
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
valid users = admin

This user when i try to login says wrong username and password, even though i do enter the right information

Comment: [dfg]
comment = dfg
path = /home/samba/admin
read only = no
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770

This user i go straight in and i can create new directories via win network and add/remove files. So, initialy, my problem is lying with how i have my security setup. Do you need me to post the whole of smb.conf?

Comment: There should be a logfile created for each samba client in dir /var/log/samba/. Post the error output msg from the window machine samba log file.

Comment: Also try to reset the samba password for admin user with `smbpasswd admin`. Use -a option with smbpasswd if you are adding smbpasswd for the user for first time. Check that the users is added to list `/etc/samba/smbusers`.

Comment: is there anyplace i can upload this for you, other wise i will have to post this in pieces for you.

Comment: please send me a blank email to test@diacomp.co.za and i will reply with the error log, if this will help. and for the spammers, this email will be deleted by day end, so, spam all you want.